# Redirect en laravel con parámetros

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-9

estoy intentando redirigir a una ruta con nombre pasando un parámetro de id.
La forma en la que lo estoy haciendo es así:

Defino la ruta en el Web.

```
Route::get('/admin/finish/{id}',[SuscripcionController::class,'finish'])->name('finish');
```

Llamo a esta ruta desde otro controlador:

```
return redirect()->route('finish',['id'=>$transaction->id]);
```

Y esto me tira el siguiente error:

Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response::setContent(): Argument #1 ($content) must be of type ?string, Illuminate\Routing\Redirector given, called in...

Cabe recalcar que $transaction->id  trae como resultado un número.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

Tal como lo indica el error, debes convertir tu número a `string`.

### Opción 1

Hacerlo `inline` (En línea) utilizando corchetes`{}` adentro de las comillas dobles:

```
return redirect()->route('finish',['id'=>"{$transaction->id}"]);
```

### Opción 2

Utilizando la función [`strval()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.strval.php):

```
return redirect()->route('finish',['id'=>strval($transaction->id)]);
```

### Opción 3

Declarando el tipo de variable `string` antes del valor numérico

```
return redirect()->route('finish',['id'=>(string)$transaction->id]);
```